# Why is the else part of my if else statement is not executing?

Tags: swift

The if else statement takes the boolean return from a function that is called, but the true part executes yet the false part doesn't. I checked the syntax and it is correct so there must be something I'm missing.

I tried using a while loop, but that won't work because it doesn't let me do anything if the return is false.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var word: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    //This is the text field
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func wordButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        word = textField.text!
        userInput()

        if true {
            Label.text = "This is a Palindrme."
        } else {
            Label.text = "This is not a Palindrome."
        }
    }

    func userInput() {
        Util.shared.isPalindrome(word: word)
    }
}
```

Im expecting the text to display in my label field.

Comment: When will `true` be anything else? You need a condition that contains a variable, not a constant value. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if true` condition is always satisfied. You should modify your userInput() method to return a boolean value, if you want to use it.

```
func userInput() -> Bool {
    return Util.shared.isPalindrome(word: word)
}
```

And then handle the result:

```
if userInput() { 
    // do something 
} else { 
    // do something else 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because it makes a comparison "is true == true?" and it will always return true, therefore never entering the else part

Answer (score 2):

Your function isn't returning anything and you're branching on an `if true` which is obviously always true (there should be a compiler warning here).

You need to update your function to actually return the value:

```
func userInput() -> Bool {
    return Util.shared.isPalindrome(word: word)
}
```

And use that value for your if statement:

```
if userInput() {
    Label.text = "This is a Palindrme."
} else {
    Label.text = "This is not a Palindrome."
}
```